# Pandas DataFrame equivalent of laravel's 'pluck' on collections

Tags: php, python, laravel, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas on python 3.6.5, I desire to achieve similar result on a DataFrame instance as the Collection's "pluck" method in Laravel. For example:

DataFrame

```
   one     two
0  beer    wine
1  beer  tomato
```

PHP Laravel code:

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('two')->toArray();
$print_r($plucked);

>> ['wine', 'tomato']
```

Desired solution (Python equivalent):

```
plucked = df.pluck('two')
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `plucked = df['two']` or possibly even `plucked = df['two'].tolist()` ?

Comment: In Dataframe, `convert( df[ 'two' ], Array );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select ell entries in a DataFrame column by simply doing:

```
storage_variable = df['Column Name']
```

So, in your case that would be:

```
plucked = df['two']
```